# How do I display errors on login form if user enters invalid credentials in Vue js 2?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, error-handling, vuejs2, vue-component

I'd like to know where I went wrong when displaying errors if a user enters invalid login credentials. Kindly help :(

I also removed parts of my firebase code since I'm unable to upload a long block of code due to stackoverflow's rules.

Here is my Login template,

```
                    <form>
                      <div @click="$emit('close')">
                        <span class="close">&#10006;</span>
                      </div>
                      <h3>Login</h3>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="email"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Email"
                          v-model="email"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">                        
                       <input
                          type="password"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Password"
                          v-model="password"
                          @keyup.enter="
                            onSubmit();
                            $emit('close');
                          "
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <slot name="footer">
                          <button
                            class="btn btn-primary"
                            type="button"
                            @click.prevent="onSubmit"
                            @click="$emit('close')"
                          >
                            Login
                          </button>
                     <div v-if="error" class="error">
                        {{error}}
                     </div>
                       
                                       
                       
                      </div>                        
                    </form>
```

And here is the backend part of it,

```
    export default {
      name: "Login",
      template: "#login",
      data: () => ({
        email: "",
        password: "",
        error: " ",
      
      }),  
  },
  methods: {
    async onSubmit() {
      try {
        const { user } = await firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password);
        
      } catch (error) { 
        this.error = error
        console.log("", error);         
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Are you able to reach 'onSubmit' when filling out the form?

Comment: Also notice you have a space in your error. `error: " "`

Comment: Also for your reference "backend" doesn't refer to the javascript portion of your vue component. Backend usually refers to code that is run on the server and not on the client.

Comment: yes the form gets submitted when filled

Comment: uh, yes by backend I referred to the options api where my firebase code resides.

Comment: Right - but your backend, technically, would be firebase itself. Not your options api code.

Comment: I tried copying your code into a component and it does not work. First, the slot does not have a closing tag. Next `@keyup.enter` has 2 function calls which doesn't seem to work either (I would suggest you only bind 1 function to an event handler).

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the clarification. I tried the same thing on a normal login component in 'views' folder, and it worked. Unfortunately, it doesn't work on my vue modal.

Answer (score 1):

This is my login Vuex Action for Firebase log in, check it out, maybe helps

```
login({ commit, dispatch }, login) {
          axiosAuth.post(`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=${API_KEY}`, {
            email: login.email,
            password: login.password,
            returnSecureToken: true
          })
            .then(response => {
    // ******************************************** //
    // response.data.token ? 'SUCCESS' : 'ERROR'
    // also examine the whole response object when entering the wrong credentials , there // should be some message pointing the fact that you have entered the wrong credentials
              console.log(response);
    // *******************************************  //
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.error(err);
            })
        },
```

Comment: Hi, appreciate your time and effort. Sadly, I'm not yet aware of vuex and axios. I'm kinda new to vue so the code above looks a bit confusing :(

Comment: I guess that your user const is the whole response, try to do a console log of user and error in catch block, when you enter wrong credentials and check if you can find some message or status that can be useful for your case.. P. S. Ignore vuex, axios is just like fetch, a webservice call. The point is to examine a responses.